# Cannot resolve symbol "actionBarActivity" - Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

A few days ago I updated my android studio and gradle to 4.4.1. When I tried to create a class main activity which extends actionbaractivity like this

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

I am getting an error "cannot resolve action bar activity". I am also getting the error in similar code such as imports and usage of the action bar activity such as

```
      import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

and

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

as well as uses of    findViewById.

Here is a screen shot for further info, I am using mac os (Sierra) and running the newest version of android studio and jdk.

Here is the error screen/panel:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqRWf.jpg

and here is the code screen/panel

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz1Mc.jpg

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `ActionBarActivity` has been deprecated for a couple of years. As ReverseEffect notes, use `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: I did this and now I have these errors when I try the emulator

Comment: Emulator: Failed to open vm 6

7:50 PM Emulator: Failed to create HAX VM

7:50 PM Emulator: No accelerator found.

7:50 PM Emulator: failed to initialize HAX: Invalid argument

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html#accel-vm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend AppCompatActivity instead.

(EDIT: I saw you made a comment about HAX, that's emulator specific. To test your emulator, you would open another AS project and see if it will open in the emulator. It may be possible that HAX isn't supported on your computer.)